# Update and refresh wpf chart

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, refresh

I'm working with chart of wpf toolkit, and I can't view the inserted data of the chart... Here is the xaml part:

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart  Height="352" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="profilo_cale_chart" Title="Profili cale" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="655" FontSize="16" Margin="252,0,0,55" Visibility="Hidden"> 
   <chartingToolkit:AreaSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" IsSelectionEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Foreground="#FF242424" Background="LightSteelBlue" />
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

And the cs:
Declaration

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{ ...  
    List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, double>> valueList = new List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, double>>(); 
...
```

Module called when a user chose two dateTime and press a button

```
private void refresh_charts(DateTime dtStart, DateTime dtEnd)
{
    valueList.Clear();
    using (ModelFoosContainer mc1 = new ModelFoosContainer())
    {
        var res_mea = (from mea in mc1.MeasureSet where (mea.datetime>= dtStart && mea.datetime <= dtEnd) orderby mea.datetime descending select mea).Take(1000);
        foreach (Measure mea1 in res_mea){
            valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime,double>(mea1.datetime, Convert.ToDouble(mea1.depth)));
        }
    }


    profilo_cale_chart.DataContext = valueList;
    //I've tried with this two but doesn't work..
    //profilo_cale_chart.Refresh();
    //this.UpdateLayout();

}
```

After this the chart has the right and not empty DataContext but doesn't show the values... anyone knows how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set name for chart series:

```
<chartingToolkit:AreaSeries Name="Example" DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" IsSelectionEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Foreground="#FF242424" Background="LightSteelBlue" />
```

and after that, set DataContext for AreaSeries:

```
Example.DataContext = valueList;
```

Comment: @Rasa I did not ask the question, I anwered it

Comment: @DaniloVulović well this is embarrassing. By mistake i mentioned u in the comment. BTW i corrected my mistake

Comment: @MicheleCappannari If answer is working for u then u should accept the answer for future reference.

Comment: @DaniloVulović Excuse-me this is the first time that I write here... So now it's accepted?

Comment: @MicheleCappannari No, it is not

Answer (score 1):

Try change "Visibility" for Chart in xaml from

```
Visibility="Hidden"
```

to

```
Visibility="Visible"
```

Comment: i've just resoleved this! Thank you anyway :)