# C# WPFToolKit Chart is not updating when updating data context

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

So I am using the WPFToolKit chart as a ColumnSeries. When I initially load the screen, the data values are properly filled into the chart. However, when I try to update the data values, the chart's data is not refreshed.

I've already tried the solution listed here [Update and refresh wpf chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12725264/update-and-refresh-wpf-chart) where I name my columnseries and update the DataContext for the columnseries instead of the Chart, but this yielded the same result.

Here is the xaml for my Chart

```
    <chartingToolkit:Chart Height="262" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="120,0,0,213" Name="Chart_Payout" Title="Payout Threshold Results" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="360">
        <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries Name ="ColumnSeries_Payout" DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Title="Payout" />
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

Here is the method I am using to update my chart

```
    private void FillPayoutChart()
    {
        chartValues.Clear();
        chartValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("$" + Payout_In.ToString("#,##0.00") + " In", Payout_In));
        chartValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("", 0));
        chartValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("$" + Payout_Out.ToString("#,##0.00") + " Out", Payout_Out));
        ColumnSeries_Payout.DataContext = chartValues;
    }
```

Payout_In and Payout_Out are both decimals declared in the WPF window class. When the window is initially opened, the chart is successfully filled with information. However, when I try to update that information after the window has been loaded, the chart is not refreshing with the new data context.

Any guidance on what I need to do to refresh the data context in the chart values?

Comment: Where are you calling `FillPayoutChart()` from? Have you tried putting a breakpoint next to `chartValues.Clear()` to see if `FillPayoutChart()` is even getting hit?

Comment: I'm calling it in the window's constructor as well as a button for updating. Like I said, it works the first time it is called while the window is actually being loaded. However, once I call it after the window has been loaded, it is filling the new data context, but it is not actually updating the chart that the user sees. It is definitely calling the method though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you override `ColumnSeries` DataContext and old binding will fail. You should change existed DataContext that you will store as a field or in an other way. Do not assign DataContext second time.

```
private void FillPayoutChart()
{
    chartValues.Clear();
    chartValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("$" + Payout_In.ToString("#,##0.00") + " In", Payout_In));
    chartValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("", 0));
    chartValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("$" + Payout_Out.ToString("#,##0.00") + " Out", Payout_Out));
    // execute next string just one time and then manipulate chartValues collection
    //ColumnSeries_Payout.DataContext = chartValues;
}
```

Of course, your chartValues should be an [`ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) or your `ColumnSeries` will not revieve an event that collection were changed.